# Facebook PHP-SDK setAccessToken NOT WORKING

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron, facebook-php-sdk

**IDEA:** 
Get event information without user interaction from various facebook pages (clubs,bars,etc..). However some pages have set that info not to be public.
**WORKING PRINCIPLE:** 
I have the latest facebook PHP-SDK on my site and an APP on facebook, so usually i call

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '387262991341732',
    'secret' => '09014d999f6e34d80ca3e62e331834cc',
));
$events = $facebook->api("$page_url/events");
```

**PROBLEM:** 
When a page is not public I have to use an access_token. 
**1)** This is an APP access-token, which is not permitted to view the events.

```
$app_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

So I figure I need to get ***user*** access_token and add more code:

```
if (!$user) {
    $args['scope'] = 'offline_access';`<br>`
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);`<br>`
}
<?php if (!$user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>`
```

I click the link by myself and use getAccessToken() to get the ***user*** access_token:

```
$user_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();// I store this in my database
```

I check this with:

```
file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/privatepage/events?access_token=$user_token');
// Everything works, im very happy
```

**2)** Now I delete all cookies, etc and try to use `$facebook->setAccessToken($user_token)` and then `$events = $facebook->api("$page_url/events");` **and get nothing**. I assure you one more time that **AccessToken is valid.**
After quite a long research im stuck with this.
**???)** ***Any Ideas how use $facebook->api(...) and not file_get_contents?**

Comment: It seems you didn't request `user_events` permission in your `getLoginUrl` parameter, that's why you can't use that graph API??  I think after facebook login, you access token is already your user access token, you don't need to setAccessToken again

Comment: user_events only gets events from the user, not from other pages...